# Check return value of malloc using Macro or User Defined function

Tags: c++, macros, malloc, user-defined-functions

Efficient way to check the return value of malloc in two ways:

1. Using Macro

   ```
    #define ALLOC(p,n) do{ *p=malloc(n*sizeof **p); } while(0)
   ```
2. User Defined Function

   ```
    static inline void *MallocOrDie(size_t MemSize)
    {
         void *AllocMem = malloc(MemSize);
         /* Some implementations return null on a 0 length alloc,
         * we may as well allow this as it increases compatibility
         * with very few side effects */
         if(!AllocMem && MemSize)
         {
              printf("Could not allocate memory!");
              exit(-1);
         }
         return AllocMem;
    }
   ```

Which is more efficient given different scenarios.

Note: Don't want to use calloc instead of malloc, since don't want to change the API's

Comment: i dont understand the comparison. The macro does not check the returned pointer. `MallocOrDie` checks it and potentially calls `exit`. Exiting or not isnt really about efficiency.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in C++?

Comment: `malloc` returns nullptr on failure, so the program will likely die anyway as soon as it tries to use it. Also, what are the odds that a call to `printf` works when you have zero memory?

Comment: @BoP Why do you think there will be zero memory just because `malloc` fails? What if the requested allocation is (say) 5 GB and only 3 GB is available?

Comment: Memory allocation in itself is pretty costly. There is no point in worrying about the efficiency of checking whether it was successful.

Comment: @Adrian - The OP seems to consider zero size allocations. I didn't realize that 0 and gigabytes were the only options.

Comment: I think both approaches are terrible, regardless of their "efficiency".  The macro doesn't check the return value of `malloc()` AT ALL, and the function only checks if a failure has occurred allocating a memory block of size zero (so will not detect a failure that occurs when allocating a block of non-zero size).    Unless you specify a *measure* of efficiency, and allow for the fact that the two "solutions" do different checks, this question is pointless.  Voting to close accordingly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a meaningless question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to change the API, consider the much simpler alternative of using `new[]` and `delete[]`. If you have no exception handler installed, failing to `new` will immediately call `std::terminate` - so you don't need your manual checks.

```cpp
#define ALLOC(p,n) *(p) = MallocOrDie((n) * sizeof *(p))

static inline void* MallocOrDie(size_t MemSize) {
    return new char[MemSize];
}

static inline void Free(void* p) {
    delete [] static_cast<char*>(p);
}
```

or as replacement for your macros:

```
template<class T>
void ALLOC(T*& p, size_t n) { p = new T[n]; }

template<class T>
void FREE(T* p) { delete[] p; }
```

This is however **not** what you *should* do. Allocate space for a number of *elements* instead of *bytes*. If you need space for `10` `int` but do not like the extra cost of zero-initializing them, use [`std::make_unique_for_overwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

```cpp
auto array = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(10);
```

This changes the API (and it *should be changed*), since you now get a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of a `void*`, but it has the benefit that when `array` goes out of scope, it'll be automatically `delete[]`ed with a lot less problems to worry about as a result. You can also directly index this smart pointer without the need for a cast, so

```cpp
{
    auto array = std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(10);
    array[9] = 123;
}
```

instead of

```cpp
{
    int* array = static_cast<int*>(MallocOrDie(10 * sizeof *array));
    array[9] = 123;
    Free(array);
}
```

---

I would however recommend that you use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for this instead. It has a small cost of zero initializing instead of default initializing - but unless you notice a problem with that, don't discard the idea. It's a easy to misuse `std::vector`s by passing them *by value* (which copies them) instead of *by reference* (which is at least as cheap as passing a pointer around) which makes new C++ programmers reluctant to using them. Just learn them and programming life will be much easier.

```
std::vector<int> array(10);
```